# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I just pushed an app to a production Heroku environment.

Basically there is a `Bus` model and it has a `seats` attribute

```
class Bus < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :seats, # other attributes
end
```

Now I have a JavaScript frontend which POST's JSON for new buses to the `buses#create` action.

ActiveRecord keeps encountering an error when I try to create a bus:

```
: POST www.busables.com/buses dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=5ms service=65ms status=500 bytes=728
: 
: ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: seats):
:   app/controllers/buses_controller.rb:31:in `new'
:   app/controllers/buses_controller.rb:31:in `create'
```

The parameters are reaching the controller action fine. I can log them and I get the folowing:

```
The bus parameters received: {"seats"=>"24", "departure_time(1i)"=>"2011", "departure_time(2i)"=>"11", "departure_time(3i)"=>"25", "departure_time(4i)"=>"16", "departure_time(5i)"=>"15", "route_attributes"=>{"summary"=>"N51", "beginning_address"=>"A place", "terminal_address"=>"Another place", "distance"=>26362, "duration"=>1753}}
```

I checked that the `Bus` table actually has the `seats` column and it does (I ran this in the Heroku console):

```
> Bus.column_names
=> ["id", "name", "route_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "price", "departure_time", "trip_distance", "trip_duration", "seats"]
```

And of course I've tried migrating and loading the database schema. I've checked that the `attr_accessible :seats` is set correctly also.

Any other ideas?

I'm running Rails 3.1.1 on the Heroku Cedar stack. Everything works fine on my local machine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's cliché but I tried again in the morning and it works perfectly! I suspect it might have been a propagation issue of some sort.

Comment: When this happens, try a 'heroku restart'. I just had this issue after running a migration, but restarting solve the problem.

Comment: I tried `heroku restart` and it didn't work for me so I googled this issue and came across this post and then realised that `heroku restart` defaults to my staging environment. forcing my production app by: `heroku restart --app myproductionapp` worked!

Comment: This must have been because you deployed the app, ran the migrations. But the app was already running, so it didn't notice the changes in db scheme. That is, you had to [restart](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15743272/52499) [it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20188292/52499).

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue with my Heroku app in production, but not with my *nearly* identical app in staging.

What was the difference? My staging app only had 1 web dyno instead of 2.

So I manually scaled my Production app down to 0 web dynos, then back up to 2.

BAM! Problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

Was pulling my hair out on this one until I saw Leito's comment above.

```
heroku restart --app staging
```

fixed this one for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
attr_reader :seats
attr_accessor :seats
```

instead of

```
attr_accessible :seats
```

Comment: The problem seems to have fixed itself overnight. Might have been a propagation issue or something. Thanks anyway.