# Heroku run rake db:migrate results in no change in the database, app restarted several times

Tags: heroku, migration, rake, database-migration, rails-migrations

I have a problem with pushing my migrations to the production database.

The issue:

1. I've altered database schema by adding 1 column.
2. I've migrated it to the production database:

   MacBook-Air-Mac:app msc$ rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="production" 
   [RailsAdmin] RailsAdmin initialization disabled by default. Pass SKIP_RAILS_ADMIN_INITIALIZER=false if you need it.
   ==  AddLengthColumnToBooks: migrating =========================================
   -- add_column(:books, :length, :integer)
      -> 0.0017s
   ==  AddLengthColumnToBooks: migrated (0.0019s) ================================
3. Thinking that the new DB schema is now in production, I've deployed the code which does some things with `:length`.
4. In production, I got the following error:

   undefined method `length=' for #
5. I did `heroku rollback` and downgraded the app to the latest reliable version.
6. THEN (a bit too late probably) I found out that I have to `heroku restart` the app to load the new indexes. I did this several times.
7. I opened the console then and checked `Book.column_names`, but there was no `length`
8. I did `heroku run rake db:migrate` followed by `heroku restart` one more time, no change.
9. I've tried migrating another column to the production db, but didn't get any message at all, not even the one from p.2.

### What am I doing wrong here?

**Update**

Based on the answers of [Philipe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405865/philipe), I did a number of additional steps:

1. `git add db/schema.rb`, `git add db/migrate/20130325103953_add_length_column_to_books.rb`
    and 'git add db/migrate/20130401041910_add_duration_column_to_books.rb'. Git's answer was:
2. Changes to be committed:
    (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)

   new file:   db/migrate/20130325103953_add_length_column_to_books.rb
   new file:   db/migrate/20130401041910_add_duration_column_to_books.rb
   modified:   db/schema.rb
3. Then I did `git commit -m "Updating the schema"`.
4. Again the output was:

   ```
    3 files changed, 168 insertions(+), 156 deletions(-)
   ```

   create mode 100644 db/migrate/20130325103953_add_length_column_to_books.rb
    create mode 100644 db/migrate/20130401041910_add_duration_column_to_books.rb
5. Then I run `heroku run rake db:migrate`. Unfortunately there was no sign of migrations, simply got:

   Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.5428
   and that's it.
6. In the production Rails Console, running `Book.column_names` still lacks both length and duration.

Now I'm even more out of ideas.
`

Comment: What was the output of `heroku run rake db:migrate`?

Comment: In pt.8, the output was: Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.4711.

Comment: So no output, thus no migration happened. Are you sure you commited the migration and schema?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry, I'm a novice in Rails, can you clarify what do you mean by commiting the migration and the schema? Should I just git commit db/schema.rb and 20130325103953_add_length_column_to_books.rb?

Comment: Yes, the code has to be commited so that it is available on Heroku.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are pushing changes to Heroku. Steps should be as follows;

1. Make changes to local code
2. Run any migrations LOCALLY
3. Add all changed files to Git `git add .`
4. Commit all added files to git `git commit -m "Adding features"`
5. Push the changes to Heroku `git push heroku master` - assuming you are using `heroku` as your remote name and you are working in the `master` branch
6. If you have migrations run `heroku run rake db:migrate` to run the migrations ON HEROKU
7. Following migrations do `heroku restart`

That should be all you need to get you working.

Comment: I have the same problem, however I took all of the steps you list and Heroku still ignores the migration completely.

Comment: I have in the past done migrations on Heroku without needing to restart, but for some reason this time it didn't work. Restarting after the migration fixed the issue.

Comment: `heroku restart` was what I was missing. Thank u!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem; I git added the migrations, git pushed them to the server, cap deployed them, and the database didn't change.  Logged in to the server directly, ran rake db:migrate, and the command line seemed to run the migration, but nothing changed.

In my case, somehow rake db:migrate was using the wrong RAILS_ENV.  I logged in to the server, and ran

rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production

This caused the database to create the new columns, and then all of the code that I had debugged in the test database started working on the server.

Answer (score 2):

I just had same problem. After adding a column to my DB locally, I did `heroku run rake db:migrate -app [my app name]`. Running my code on production, I got `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute '_____' for [table name].)`

This solved my problem:

`heroku restart --app [my app name]`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to run the migration on `Heroku` for your `postgresql` database you can add this line in your `Procfile`

```bash
release: alembic upgrade head
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents based on my experience: I thought that `heroku run db:migrate` also migrated db content into production. No! Only structure. So in my case, log in was not working in production because there were no users in it. I had to sign test user up again and then it worked. Hope it helps rookies like me out there