# Heroku doesn't see my changes after git push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy a new version of my app to heroku and although running it locally works, I can't see any change after I do the following:

```
git push heroku master
```

and then

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

There seems to be no effect.  It's strange because without a model change I was able to deploy changes with just the git push command.  Any thoughts?

Comment: More info... checked the git on heroku and it has my last commit?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if you might be not commiting your changes to Github first.

```
git add .

git commit -m "commit details here"

git push origin master
```

THEN

```
git push heroku master
```

Comment: When I git status on my local version there is nothing to commit on the master branch.  I am not using Github.

Comment: had forgotten to commit ^_^ thanks for remembering me :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're pushing and then migrating you then need to do

```
heroku restart
```

to have your application recache the DB schema.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and posted what worked for me in response to others' similar issues:

[$git push heroku master - no error messages but changes not displaying on web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769088/git-push-heroku-master-no-error-messages-but-changes-not-displaying-on-web-ap)

[git push heroku master says "Everything up-to-date", but the app is not current](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947406/git-push-heroku-master-says-everything-up-to-date-but-the-app-is-not-current/31208756)