# git push heroku master - no error messages but changes not displaying on web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, heroku

After installing the devise gem to create users on my web app, my changes are not appearing on the live app.

I believe I am running the correct code in terminal (I am following the one-month-rails course):

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "message"
$ git push  
$ git push heroku master
```

The push to heroku runs through and I don't receive an error message, however, when I try to access my heroku page

```
$ heroku open
```

The changes are not displayed on the live web-app.

All the changes are displayed when running the rails server on the localhost. Furthermore, the activity log on the heroku website shows that my push went through and that its running the same version as my most recent push to github.

Any thoughts?

Best,
Brian

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but I was away traveling. It turns out I was pushing to a different path in GitHub. Not entirely sure how I was pushing to a different path, it must have been during a revert that I diverged from master.

Answer (score 3):

** Also posted this response here: [git push heroku master says "Everything up-to-date", but the app is not current](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947406/git-push-heroku-master-says-everything-up-to-date-but-the-app-is-not-current/31208756#31208756)

Even though this is an old issue, I wanted to update with what worked for me (a newbie) should anyone else run into this:

After following the instructions here (from Hudson), what finally did the trick for me was doing a "git pull" after checking out the "master" branch. Perhaps "git push heroku master" pushes out only the local branch of master?

Of course, this assumes all required changes have been correctly merged into your master. I hadn't pulled from master on my local since the project set up because all merges (from development to master) were handled on GitHub and I had been working on new branches that were later merged with development.

So, to restate steps above from Hudson:

`git checkout master`

`git pull`

(here, I updated README to have a change to commit, like "Heroku deploy [date, time]"

`git add .`

`git commit -am "xxxyyzzz"`

`git push heroku master`

`heroku run rake db:migrate`

`heroku restart`

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve my issue only by making a new_branch and pushing that on heroku:

```
git checkout -b new_branch
git add .
git commit -m "Just a test commit to push new branch to heroku"
git push heroku new_branch:master
heroku restart
```

Comment: I had the same issue with a MERN app. This solution fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should take care of following things when you have your hands on **heroku**

1. run pending migrations if any `heroku run rake db:migrate`
2. restart your heroku app after successful run of migrations `heroku restart` not needed if you have only code changes, but a good practice to do.
3. verify assets are getting compiled properly on a push, if not you can `heroku run rake assets:precompile`

Comment: Everything looked great on both my local and remote code bases but for reason heroku wouldn't show the updates, even after rake db:migrate. `heroku restart` saved the day. THANK YOU!