# Refspec Not a Valid Name

Tags: git, heroku

I am reading a book because I'm trying to teach myself, but I am stumped.

I keep using `git push heroku master` to push my result, but when I go to the url provided, it says the page I am looking for does not exist.

Here is what I have done:
1. Successfully ran `git push heroku master` without any error messages.
2. I looked at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769088/git-push-heroku-master-no-error-messages-but-changes-not-displaying-on-web-ap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769088/)

(the link button is not working, it keeps asking me for a tag but no matter what I do, it won't let me correctly format the link.)

Can you guys help me trouble shoot what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I did wrong:

1. There was nothing wrong with how I was using the git commands.
2. I needed to edit the router file. I had nothing in here originally.
3. I also needed to edit the controller action file. I had nothing in here originally.

Problem is now solved.

I am new to this :)