# git push heroku master everything up to date but the app doesn't update

Tags: git, reactjs, heroku, repository, push

So I can see the changes locally, but even after a successful push to heroku, it still doesn't reflect those changes. I've tried everything suggested in this link but to no luck so I'm not so sure what's going on.

[git push heroku master says "Everything up-to-date", but the app is not current](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947406/git-push-heroku-master-says-everything-up-to-date-but-the-app-is-not-current)

Also, I've checked that the heroku git repository does indeed contain the new files and it does so I don't know why heroku doesn't load them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try opening it in another browser or in incognito because it could be cached in your current browser to serve the old files. You should also clear the cache of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

it might be service worker... so it never loads page (it load drom catch) if you use CRA. Also, Check if you have proc file and if it bundles correctly. But first try to reload page on <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd>

Comment: Yeah, I reloaded the page a couple of times but still doesn't change. Also, I don't think I have a proc file, so I assume it's something with service worker then? How can I fix it? I'm still a beginner with this whole environment so still getting used to all these issues

Comment: if you refreshed with ctrl+f5 it is not service worker... on heroku proc file is command that heroku executes so it runs website(same command you run in terninal) i dont know if isnt this

Comment: I didn't refresh with ctrl + f5. I just pressed the reload page button of chrome. I don't know if the command you're referring to is heroku open? Also, if this isn't what you mean by ctrl + f5, I don't know how to execute ctrl + f5 on a mac since the keys are different. Do you know the right combination?

Comment: Apparently it works when I open it in incognito so I'm assuming it's cached somewhere in my browser.