# How to get the right redirection from email when reset password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have Sample App by Michael Hartl's  “Ruby on Rails Tutorial”.

If I click on “Forget Password”, I've got email notification and if click on  link “Reset password”, I’ve got redirected to the wrong app that doesn’t exist and I could  see  only  empty page.

> https://wrong.com/password_resets/WTk_raloURf8I8sCaXNNkg/edit?email=tatyana_p%70yahoo.com

That wrong app existed earlier but was already deleted. 
The code as below shows the correct host but   the redirection happened   to the wrong host.

`ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME']` and `ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD']` are correct.

I could not find a wrong name of the host anywhere else in code and change  it to the correct one.

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
host = 'correct_host.herokuapp.com'
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port           => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain         => 'heroku.com',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

If I copy and paste an address that I've got when I click on "Reset password"
and changed the wrong address on the right one - I've got the right fields for  a password  and confirming password.

> https://correct_host.herokuapp.com/password_resets/WTk_raloURf8I8sCaXNNkg/edit?email=tatyana_p%70yahoo.com

Comment: How do your mailer and your mailer's view look like?

Comment: I've got  everything exactly as in Michael Hartl tutorial except I could not reset password. I could not figure out where to change the wrong host to the right one.

Comment: Yes,  I initially used this wrong host: I git clone from heroku, directory when I've cloned there was empty dir. and I did something about it follow heroku direction and in process I've change the name of the host for the right .  Is anything can be done to make it work like commit/anything else?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44173405/10608621) to solve problem with Git and Heroku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make commit for right host

First go to your `master` branch

```
git checkout master
```

Then edit your `config/environments/production.rb` with right host.

And then

```
git add config/environments/production.rb
git commit -m "Right host"
git push heroku
```

Comment: it said that nothing to commit and everything up-to-date. I need to change wrong host to the right one and those command change nothing.

Comment: Actually it was on master. But it doesn't solve problem since in this file production.rb the host is correct but it still go the  wrong when I try to reset password.

Comment: @TM, type `heroku run bash` and then `cat config/environments/production.rb`. And check that host is right

Comment: there is wrong host. 
but when I've opened config/environments/production.rb - there is the right one....

Comment: So you have to do commit. That's your problem

Comment: And you don't need to change application_routes

Comment: I be able change host using those command but after changing it the app. got other error...but it is the different question:)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Devise and its default mailer views I'd advise to check your `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options` (since Devise uses `edit_password_url` path helper to build url).

Comment: I don't use any Devise and routes.rb don't indicates any path to change.

Comment: Ok, anyway make sure that `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options` has relevant host. Also, as @spickermann said, it'd be helpful if you show us your mailer's views.

Comment: I googled the tutorial you mentioned https://www.railstutorial.org/book/password_reset#cha-password_reset
According to chapter 6, Listing 12.9 the mailer's views should be in `app/views/user_mailer` directory, they look fine.
Did you check `default_url_options` ? (open console, navigate to project's root directory, type `rails c` [Enter], type `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options` [Enter], the output should looks like `{:host=>"your-domain.com"}`, also what's the output of `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.edit_password_reset_url('test_token', email: 'test@example.com')` ?)

Comment: `rails c -e production`

Comment: 2.4.5 :001 > Rails.application.routes.default_url_options
 => {}
it is empty  how to add. the right host?
 Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.edit_password_reset_url('test_token', email: 'test@example.com') ?
2.4.5 :005 >
no output and no errors.

Comment: I put it but could not push heroku
ttps://git.heroku.com/correct.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/correct.git

Comment: Aww, I missed `?` in ternary operation, it should be `Rails.env.production? ? 'correct_host.herokuapp.com' : 'localhost'`.

Comment: I add. only one line . Need to add something else? 
host: Rails.env.production? 'correct_host.herokuapp.com' : 'localhost'

Comment: it's crashed looks like syntax error again;
ake aborted!
 !     SyntaxError: /tmp/build_b82ef64800b9a08f9b59e512724a9f4b/config/application.rb:30: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting '}'
 !     host: Rails.env.production? 'https://correct.herokuapp.com

Comment: Please see my previous comment (I missed question mark in ternary operation).

Comment: I put second ? but app.crashed ...
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = {
      host: Rails.env.production?  ?  'correct_host.herokuapp.com' : 'localhost'
    }

Comment: It crashed because of syntax error? Could you show the error log? You can use https://pastebin.com if it's too long.

Comment: Process exited with status 1
2019-03-30T19:29:17.725955+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=correct.herokuapp.com request_id=683897b5-53fd-4bf3-810c-d8179b408809 fwd="108.211.182.6" dyno= connect= service= status=50

Comment: @TM, stop crash your app. You don't need to change that. Your problem is that your local file and file on Heroku server are different. Rollback all your changes and carefully commit changes of right host