# Project is not pushed in Heroku

Tags: reactjs, git, heroku

So I want to push all the new changes of my project in Heroku. However, all the changes are pushed straight away to my own [GitHub](https://github.com/theo82/expensify-react-app) repository instead of Heroku.

I am getting this

```
git push heroku production:master
Everything up-to-date
```

With remote -v

```
heroku  git@github.com:theo82/expensify-react-app.git (fetch)
heroku  git@github.com:theo82/expensify-react-app.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:theo82/expensify-react-app.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:theo82/expensify-react-app.git (push)
```

my realeases in Heroku's git are

```
v10  Set FIREBASE_API_KEY, FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN, FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL, FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID, FIREBA…  email@gmail.com  2020/06/04 08:56:20 +0300 (~ 23m ago)
v9   Remove KEY config vars                                                                           email@gmail.com  2020/06/04 08:52:11 +0300 (~ 27m ago)
v8   Set KEY config vars                                                                              email@gmail.com  2020/06/04 08:45:03 +0300 (~ 34m ago)
v7   Deploy 3284670f                                                                                  email@gmail.com  2020/05/28 08:01:17 +0300
v6   Deploy 8a0c21d0                                                                                  email@gmail.com  2020/05/27 19:36:41 +0300
v5   Deploy b128207e                                                                                  email@gmail.com  2020/05/27 18:01:10 +0300
v4   Deploy 21c22fda                                                                                  email@gmail.com  2020/05/25 19:26:36 +0300
v3   Deploy 36ba978f                                                                                  email@gmail.com  2020/05/22 09:39:14 +0300
v2   Enable Logplex                                                                                   email@gmail.com  2020/05/22 08:58:26 +0300
v1   Initial release                                                                                  email@gmail.com  2020/05/22 08:58:26 +0300
```

Surely, I messed up something but I can't see where. I tried the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947406/git-push-heroku-master-says-everything-up-to-date-but-the-app-is-not-current), but still have the same problem. How can I fix it?

Thanks,
Theo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your heroku git remote is wrongly configured.

```
$ git remote -v
heroku  git@github.com:theo82/expensify-react-app.git (fetch)
heroku  git@github.com:theo82/expensify-react-app.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:theo82/expensify-react-app.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:theo82/expensify-react-app.git (push)
```

They are all pointing to your GitHub. You need to fix the Heroku remote. First remove the Heroku remote

```
$ git remote rm heroku
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:theo82/expensify-react-app.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:theo82/expensify-react-app.git (push)
```

Determine the link of your Heroku remote.

[image]

add the Heroku remote.

```
$ git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/yourappname.git
$ git remote -v
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/yourappname.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/yourappname.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:theo82/expensify-react-app.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:theo82/expensify-react-app.git (push)
```

Push with `git push heroku master`